# Assistance converting SQL query to a LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

They told me to write the codes that I wrote with SQL query with LINQ. But I couldn't quite do it. Can someone who knows help me?

My SQL code:

```
        DropDownListInvoiceTown.Items.Clear();
        Session["ilID"] = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListInvoiceCity.SelectedValue);
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = ENKITEST; Initial Catalog = FAZIKI; User ID = WebAdmin; Password = !ConAdmin");
        SqlCommand kmt = new SqlCommand();
        kmt.Connection = cnn;
        kmt.CommandText = "SELECT wt.IDTown as IlceID, wt.TownName as IlceAdi FROM ArkadasWebSite.dbo.WebArkadasCities as wc JOIN ArkadasWebSite.dbo.WebArkadasTowns as wt on wc.IDCity = wt.IDTown WHERE wc.IDCity=@DropDownListInvoiceCity ORDER BY wc.CityName";
        kmt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DropDownListInvoiceCity", DropDownListInvoiceCity.SelectedValue);
        SqlDataReader oku;
        cnn.Open();
        oku = kmt.ExecuteReader();
        DropDownListInvoiceTown.DataSource = oku;
        DropDownListInvoiceTown.DataValueField = "IlceID";
        DropDownListInvoiceTown.DataTextField = "IlceAdi";
        DropDownListInvoiceTown.DataBind();
        cnn.Close();
```

If the code I fixed is:

```
   DropDownListInvoiceTown.Items.Clear();
            Session["ilID"] = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListInvoiceCity.SelectedValue);
            DropDownListInvoiceTown.DataSource = arkadas.WebArkadasCities.Where(x => x.IDCity == arkadas.WebArkadasTowns.Where(w => w.IDTown == DropDownListInvoiceCity.SelectedValue).Select(w => w.TownName).FirstOrDefault()).Select(x => x.CityName).ToList();
            DropDownListInvoiceTown.DataValueField = "IlceID";
            DropDownListInvoiceTown.DataTextField = "IlceAdi";
            DropDownListInvoiceTown.DataBind();
```

But it doesn't work so it returns empty. How can I do it?

Comment: A good start would be to find an O/R mapper that supports LINQ.

Comment: @GertArnold OP is already using a LINQ mapper, that is actually their entire point, they want help to convert their previous SQL attempt to LINQ

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I don't see any reference to a "LINQ mapper". Yeah, `arkadas.WebArkadasCities`, but what is it? It's always crucial to know *exactly* which ORM is used and what the class model looks like. As usual, people start posting LINQ statements including joins, but these manual joins should hardly ever be necessary if navigation properties are in place.

Comment: @GertArnold It is actually _irrelevant_ which ORM is being used, this question is a simple convert SQL to LINQ expression request. Yes joins may not be necessary, and that is dependant on the model, but it is still valid to use them if you want to. There is enough here for a top quality answer.

Comment: @burak can you please update your post to include a definfition of the `WebArkadasCities` and `WebArkadasTowns` classes to recieve a reliable answer that you can use without us having to make assumptions.

Comment: Also @burak is the join in the original SQL correct? does the following really define the relationship `wc.IDCity = wt.IDTown` it is an unusual naming convention and looks more like a simple typo.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that I was trying to do this. Now I have city and county tables. The two have features to sync up. In other words, the id of the province is related to the province id of the district. I made the table, and in the sql query I wrote, it is obvious what I got. I just need to convert the sql to linq. @ChrisSchaller

Comment: @GertArnold I think you understood what I want to do. I think there is no problem with the synchronization in sql. The code works as the sql above. But they asked me to do it with linq.

Comment: but @burak Why are you ordering by `CityName` when that is not in the output... its just a very strange model implementation so its hard to determine if this is a typo or not, and if there is a typo, you wont be able to use the answers that we post.

Comment: As follows, when the user first selects the dropdownlist field for the sales site, the district names should appear automatically in the other dropdownlist field. For example, there are 15 values in the database with IDCity= 01 in the province table and IDTown=01 in the county table. These have to come. @ChrisSchaller

Comment: @ChrisSchaller "simple convert SQL to LINQ expression requests" don't exist. Believe me, I've seen enough frustrating efforts in this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately we want to convert a SQL expression to a LINQ expression. This answer assumes that you are using an ORM or at least LINQ to SQL, and that the original SQL is a correct statement that returns the expected recordset.

- If the original SQL is not correct, then this LINQ solution will no help, this is instead general guidance on how to translate your SQL to LINQ.

Given this SQL:

```sql
SELECT wt.IDTown as IlceID, wt.TownName as IlceAdi 
FROM ArkadasWebSite.dbo.WebArkadasCities as wc 
JOIN ArkadasWebSite.dbo.WebArkadasTowns as wt on wc.IDCity = wt.IDTown 
WHERE wc.IDCity=@DropDownListInvoiceCity 
ORDER BY wc.CityName
```

> They told me to write the codes that I wrote with SQL query with LINQ

Linq has a query notation that you can use that is very similar to SQL, you can see the following is a direct conversion of the original query, the main thing to note is that the order of the clauses is different and the syntax swapped around a bit, but it is very recognisable to those fluent in SQL.

```
var linqQuery = from wc in arkadas.WebArkadasCities
                where wc.IDCity == DropDownListInvoiceCity.SelectedValue                 
                join wt in arkadas.WebArkadasTowns on wc.IDCity equals wt.IDTown
                order by wc.CityName
                select new {
                    IlceID = wt.IDTown,
                    IlceAdi = wt.TownName
                };
```

The same query can be written using the linq *fluent* notation:

```
var linqQuery = arkadas.WebArkadasCities.Where(wc => wc.IDCity == DropDownListInvoiceCity.SelectedValue)
                                        .Join(arkadas.WebArkadasTowns, wc => wc.IDCity, wt => wt.IDTown, (wc, wt) => new 
                                            {
                                                wt.IDTown,
                                                wt.TownName,
                                                wc.CityName
                                            })
                                        .OrderBy(x => x.CityName)
                                        .Select(x => new 
                                            {
                                                IlceID = x.IDTown,
                                                IlceAdi = x.TownName
                                            });
```

Then you can use this `linqQuery` reference, however you choose to define it, in your original code:

```
DropDownListInvoiceTown.Items.Clear();
Session["ilID"] = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListInvoiceCity.SelectedValue);
DropDownListInvoiceTown.DataSource = linqQuery.ToList();
DropDownListInvoiceTown.DataValueField = "IlceID";
DropDownListInvoiceTown.DataTextField = "IlceAdi";
DropDownListInvoiceTown.DataBind();
```

---

If you are using an ORM, and there is a navigation property defined between the `WebArkadasCities` and `WebArkadasTowns` then the linq query can be greatly simplified by omitting the join.

> The following query makes assumptions about your model that may not exist, in this case we assume that `WebArkadasTowns` has a navigation property called `City` that links the *towns* to the *city* that they belong to. In this example it is assumed that there are multiple *towns* for each *city*.
>
> This assumption is based on the general expectation that a town is smaller than a city, and it matches my local context where a *town* is called a *suburb* and a city is a *municipality* (or *province*)
>
> In this scenario, we will also transpose the query to select from the `WebArkadasTowns` as this makes a cleaner query. I have left in the artifacts from the original query that are defined for us automatically thanks to the navigation property.

*Query Notation:*

```
var linqQuery = //from wc in arkadas.WebArkadasCities
                from wt in arkadas.WebArkadasTowns// on wc.IDCity equals wt.IDTown
                where wt.City.IDCity == DropDownListInvoiceCity.SelectedValue 
                order by wt.City.CityName
                select new {
                    IlceID = wt.IDTown,
                    IlceAdi = wt.TownName
                };
```

Fluent Notation:

```
var linqQuery = arkadas.WebArkadasTowns.Where(wt => wt.City.IDCity == DropDownListInvoiceCity.SelectedValue)
                                       .OrderBy(wt => wt.City.CityName)
                                       .Select(wt => new 
                                            {
                                                IlceID = wt.IDTown,
                                                IlceAdi = wt.TownName
                                            });
```

Comment: Here is exactly the answer I was looking for, both in a descriptive and instructive way. Thank you very much sir, what you told is very understandable and instructive. Thanks to you, I learned more or less about the linq query. I can't thank you enough. Many thanks again. @ChrisSchaller

Comment: It makes it easier to post detailed answers if you provide more detail next time ;) I don't like _guessing_ where data models are concerned, but sometimes you just have to take the risk. I wish you well on your linq journey. I leave you with this quote: "Every SQL result set can be produced via Linq, but that doesn't mean that you should, or that it would generate efficient SQL". There is always a way, but sometimes a compromise between LINQ and SQL can produce the best result.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Query

```
arkadas.WebArkadasCities
.Join(arkadas.WebArkadasTowns, wc=> wc.IDCity, wt=> wt.IDTown, (wc, wt) => new {wc, wt})
.where(x=> x.wt.IDCity==DropDownListInvoiceCity.SelectedValue)
.Select(s=> new 
{
IlceID=s.wt.IDTown,
IlceAdi=s.wt.TownName
}).OrderBy(o => o.IlceID).ToList();
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your effort. I tried your code you wrote, sir, but the district names could not be loaded according to the province name. @NagibMahfuz